# Where syntax in Laravel 5 with paginate feature, search feature

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

On my website, Users can see personal data, search by data or by date and see paginated results.

I'm having trouble to get the paginated data of a user with his "userID" using `->where` keyword which need to be integrated in a search feature.

However, I have logic errors and was wondering if someone could help me.

---

This is my Controller

```
    public function index()
{
    $q='';
    $from = '';
    $to = '';

    if (Input::get('dateSearchFrom') !='' && Input::get('dateSearchTo') !='') {
        $from = Input::get('dateSearchFrom').' 00:00:00.000';
        $to = Input::get('dateSearchTo').' 23:59:59.999';
    }else if (Input::get('search') !='') {
        $q = Input::get('search');
    }

    if ($q != '') {
        $incomes = Income::latest('created_at')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('name','like','%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('money','like','%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('created_at','like','%'.$q.'%')->paginate(4);
    }else if (Input::get('dateSearchFrom') !='' && Input::get('dateSearchTo') !='') {
        $incomes = Income::latest('created_at')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orWhereBetween('created_at', array($from, $to))->paginate(4);

    }else{
        $incomes = Income::latest('created_at')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(4);
    }

    $incomes->setPath('income');
    return view('member.income.list')->with([
        'title' => 'Income Data',
        'incomes' => $incomes,
        ]);
}
```

and this is my model

```
    use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'incomes';

protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'user_id',
    'description',
    'money'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated

I realised after I posted this that the suggested syntax is also incorrect. You are not giving much in the way of an error so it's hard to solve your problem. I cannot find `Model::latest()` but I assumed that you already had that covered.

It looks as if you're trying to paginate results ordering by created_at in descending order. If so, this would be the correct syntax:

```php
$incomes = Income::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4);
```

I wrongly thought that `->get()` is all that was necessary as I believed it worked on my copy but I ran into an error.

#### Original

Have you tried using `->get()`? Like this:

```php
$incomes = Income::latest('created_at')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->paginate(4);`
```